# How can I display and utilize a php file into my Xcode project?

Tags: php, html, swift, uiwebview, localhost

I am using a website I am developing on localhost, and I would like to either display the localhost url, of the files from the website onto my Xcode project.  The problem isn't really displaying the material, if I choose to display the files as a .html file, but I am really struggling to find a way to both display the website and capture the php data at the same time.  I've tried this code

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {
    @IBOutlet weak var webView: UIWebView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        let URL = NSURL(string: "http://localhost/home.php")

        webView.loadRequest(NSURLRequest(URL: URL!))
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }


}
```

and nothing works, but it does work for google.com and others.

Comment: You have to implement an HTTP request to the php file to actually get any data from it.  What does the php file consist of, you may be better of doing this another way if you explain the situation better.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to be able to run the PHP code, you will need to spawn a PHP sever **inside** your app. As you discovered, a local `.html` file can be displayed by `UIWebView`, or any browser, but PHP is not a browser, but a server-side language.

If you must have dynamic behavior in your page, then an alternative is to write it in Javascript.